# How to create a WPF window editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, graphics, graph

I am not sure where to even begin to look for information on this so I am hoping that someone here can provide some direction.

I would like to create a WPF window designer.  The idea is to have a library of custom controls that define logic as well as a control that can be placed on a WPF window that will show the status of the logic visually.

The window can be edited in visual studio but the trick is to incorporate run-time editing capability.  The WPF application will be run and a "designer mode" can be activated to show a toolbox with all available controls.  The controls can be dragged to the actively selected window and configured through a pop-up.  Some controls will just be graphical such as lines, but most will have underlying logic to show information.

This would be similar to a HMI, and while I have found libraries that allow HMI design using visual studio, I could not find anything on how to build a basic run-time editor as described above.

I plan on using MEF in the application, so I think I know how to create the libraries and load them with MEF.  I will need to include in each library a user control and any underlying logic.

I am thinking I will need to include a "toolbox image" for each control and this is what will need to be loaded into the toolbox.  Drag-drop will be used and when drag-drop is started somehow I need to create the user control for the user to drop onto the window surface.

Now it would turn into a WPF window editor and I am not sure how to go about getting that functionality.  ie. be able to move the control after it has already been dropped. Serialize the window to a XAML file that can be loaded again on next run.

Is there any guidance on doing these sorts of things?  I have been reading into graph editor examples and HMI examples but nothing really shows how to work with a user/custom control.

Comment: Why do you need this? I can imagine, what you have a big form and you want to let user to choose, where, when and which info to see. This could be achieved by docking, using MDI, by creating a limited list of available *windows* with some additional properties. But letting user to put just any control from your list many times in any place on the form? It's too flexible and required too much configuration. The user may be ok with selecting theme (predefined setup) from the list, but they don't like dealing with *a lot* of options anyway. So.. why?

Comment: I need this functionality since the same pieces will be used for many different projects.  The only difference between them is the layout and addressing where each piece talks to.  After the project is deployed it is a requirement to be able to add move or remove pieces using the software during run time without having to use visual studio or to have to re build. The end functionally will be very similar to most HMI software packages. I think I have ideas on how to try approach everything except for the run time design and save./serialize part.

Comment: Maybe you could create modules and make them configurable, while having a solution to display it. It's much more simple and realistic. If something appears more than once - make it a control, which you can create dynamically, add properties to it, have array of configurations for a number of such properties, have a framework behind to present it (to example, simple `Grid` can hold multiple of controls) -> done.